# Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF6AD8E1173: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: c++, массивы

Код программы:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Month {
    int countDay;
    int countHour = 24;
    int** monthTable;
};

int enterMonth(int*);
void randomGenerateArray(int**, int, int, int);

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    Month mon;
    
    int numbMonth = enterMonth(&mon.countDay);
    //ініціалізація масиву
    mon.monthTable = new int* [mon.countDay];
    for (int i = 0; i < mon.countDay; i++) {
        mon.monthTable[i] = new int[mon.countHour];
    }

    cout << "\nПрограма автоматично згенерує значення температури, відповідно до пори року\n";

    randomGenerateArray(mon.monthTable, mon.countDay, mon.countHour, numbMonth);

    return 0;
}

int enterMonth(int *countDay) {
    int numbMonth;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Введіть номер місяця, протягом якого заміряли температуру: ";
        cin >> numbMonth;
        if (numbMonth > 0 && numbMonth <= 12) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Число місяців - 12!\n";
        }
    }
    if (numbMonth == 2) {
        *countDay = 28;
    }
    else if (numbMonth == 1 || numbMonth == 3 || numbMonth == 5 || numbMonth == 7 || numbMonth == 8 || numbMonth == 10 || numbMonth == 12) {
        *countDay = 31;
    }
    else if (numbMonth == 4 || numbMonth == 6 || numbMonth == 9 || numbMonth == 11) {
        *countDay = 30;
    }
    return numbMonth;
}

void randomGenerateArray(int **arr, int day, int hours, int countMon) {
    //установлює діапазони температури, відповідно до пори року
    int max, min;
    if (countMon <= 2 || countMon == 12) {
        max = 35;
        min = 25;
    }
    else if ((countMon <= 5 && countMon >= 3) || (countMon <= 11 && countMon >= 9)) {
        max = 25;
        min = 5;
    }
    else if (countMon <= 8 || countMon >= 6) {
        max = 25;
        min = -10;
    }
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < day; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < hours; i++) {
            //наступний рядок викликає помилку
            arr[i][j] = (rand() % max) - min;
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF6AD8E1173 в LabWork6.exe:
> 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу
> 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам всё портит одна маленькая опечатка во вложенном цикле:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < day; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < hours; i++) { // Здесь ведь должно быть j++
            //наступний рядок викликає помилку
            arr[i][j] = (rand() % max) - min;
        }
    }
```

В таком виде, как у Вас есть сейчас, счётчик цикла `i` у Вас наращивается в двух циклах, а проверяется только в одном, в результате чего выходит за границы массива. Замените во втором цикле `i++` на `j++` и всё заработает.

P.S. Используйте отладчик при возникновении таких исключений. Он укажет строку, в которой произошла ошибка и значения переменных на момент её возникновения, что позволит Вам самому находить подобные опечатки.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: @РоманПроценко, Всегда рад помочь :) если мой ответ был полезен, примите его как правильный и проголосуйте.